# How many minimal AVL trees given height?

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

I am having trouble finding the formula for the amount of minimal AVL trees given a certain height. To clarify my understanding of height = 0 is 1 node and height = 1 is 2 nodes.

At first I calculate how many nodes there are in a minimal AVL Tree with the Fibonacci formula (Fib(3+h)-1). For example:

- h(1) = Fib(3+1) - 1 = 2 Nodes
- h(2) = Fib(3+2) - 1 = 4 Nodes
- ...

With this information i tried to draw all possible trees for the given height:

- h(1) = 2  minimal AVL Trees
- h(2) = 4  minimal AVL Trees
- h(3) = 10 minimal AVL Trees

But from height 3 on I'm not really sure if I got all of them. Am I maybe missing something or is there maybe as specific formula I can use?

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think there's a recurrence T(-1) = 1, T(0) = 1, T(n) = 2 T(n-1) T(n-2), which would mean 2^Fib(h+2)?

Comment: The recurrence mentioned by David is based on a simple way of systematically producing the trees: the children of a minimal AVL tree of height n are a minimal AVL tree of height n-1 and a minimal AVL tree of height n-2. (The multiplication by two is because the higher tree could be the left child or the right child.) So if you have produced all the trees of height n-2 and height n-1, it's easy (though tedious) to enumerate all the trees of height n.